# XQuery "The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup." error on where clause

Tags: xquery

The exact error message I am getting through oXygen editor is "The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup."

The part of the query that is causing the error is the following

```
            for $top at $ind in $probSort
            where $ind <= 20
            return $top
```

According to the error message the exact text causing the error is "= 20", when I remove the "where" line the query executes perfectly and outputs the results with no error.

What exactly is going wrong because I am at a loss after two days of searching?

Thanks in advance.

--edit

First of all, i have fixed the code by changing

```
collection(resolve-uri("../folder_name"))
```

to

```
collection(resolve-uri("./?select=*.xml"))
```

which allows me to use the symbol "<=".

I wonder what makes the difference between the two version of collection(). Could somebody elaborate?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

```
where $ind le 20
```

instead of

```
where $ind <= 20
```

?

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you, however, I'm still confused as to why the error occured. I've seen many examples of "<=" being used in xquery queries and many of my peers have succesfully created queries using the symbols.

Comment: Hm, good question. I'm always trying to avoid the usage of `<` or `>` as operators in expressions.